# a mesurable function and bounded a.e is of bounded variation?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, bounded-variation

Let $F:[0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a measurable function, bounded a.e

Does this imply that $F$ is of bounded variation on $[0,1]$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, let $F$ be the indicator of the rational numbers. Then $F$ is bounded everywhere, measurable, and infinite variation.

Answer (score 2):

Not even true if we assume in addition that $F$ is continuous:
\begin{align}
F(x) &= \sin\frac{1}{x},\quad 0<x\le 1,
\\
F(0) &= 0
\end{align}

Comment: I hope I can accept to response :) +1

Comment: what if $F\in L^1[0,1]$?

Comment: Yes, this function (and nullUser's function) is in $L^1[0,1]$.